# github API v3 - acquiring access token through CURL

Tags: php, curl, github

I've been puzzling through the github API docs (v3) and I'm kind of stumped. For the initial step - the acquisition of the access token - it appears that the only way to do it within a web app is to rely on a callback URL, which gets posted a temporary code. That's then used in subsequent queries to their API.

Does anyone know if this can all be done in a single step, e.g. cURL - i.e. within a single block of code in one page? Passing off control flow to a different URL causes innumerable problems for my particular scenario.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the nature of OAuth. You could you try to use the [basic authentication method](http://developer.github.com/v3/#authentication), but if that doesn't fit your needs, then PHP has an [OAuth library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php) that should make authentication pretty painless. There are also a few PHP wrappers out there for the Github API, e.g. [php-github-api](https://github.com/ornicar/php-github-api).

Comment: Thanks, scsizzo! Not the answer I hoped, but very fair. :)

Comment: If this answers your question, then you should "accept" it so others know it's been answered.